# how to convert from IEnumerable<type> to type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF 4 with repository pattern which has the generic query method shown below:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) 
    { 
        return objectSet.Where(filter); 
    }
```

I know I can select a complete object like this:

```
context.PeriodRepository.Query(a => a.EntityId == selectedEntityId);
```

But I want to pass a Linq query that returns it as `type` instead of `IEnumerable<type>` using a LINQ expression without changing the method. Please advise me how to do that.

Comment: You mean, you want a single result? Try adding `.SingleOrDefault()` to the end of your command.

Comment: @AndreCalil query is already returning single result but the thing is return type of funtion is Enumarable<T> and I want to get result into just an object of that type not IEnumarable<T>.

Comment: Now I see what you want. Well, that would the method signature and not the argument, so I believe that you should write a second method. This method would use the current `Query` method, but would call `SingleOrDefault` and would have the return type of `T` instead of the collection

Comment: @AndreCalil in general is there a way to convert IEnumarable<type> to type object ?

Comment: The *most* general way is getting the first element, like `[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Query describes the operations performed on the list; you must perform the query to get the result(s).

Using `.ToList()`/`.ToArray()` will return all items that match the query.  Use `.First()` to get the first item that matches or `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item or the default value for no matches.

The default value for a class is `null`.

I think your code should be like this:

```
var myMatch = context.PeriodRepository
   .Query(a => a.EntityId == selectedEntityId)
   .First();
```

Also note that, `First()` will throw an exception when there is no match.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Schneider. it really helped. Just one clarification please. Using var how I just can query the only property and not full object. I want to write a query which get just first element and from first element it return only requried property.

context.Signatories1Repository.Query((a => a.Id == obj.Id).First().Select(x=>x.Name));

Comment: After `.First` you have a object, so you can just access the property.  Like `.Query(...).First().Name` will give you the Name of the first item that matches the query.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` methods and pass in a predicate to find the element you want if it is not the first.

Comment: it is only item so it is unique. The things is my method is returning IEnumarable<type> and I have type object. I want to convert IEnumarable<type> to type. please advice

Comment: IEnumerable<type> is returning a collection or list of elements. There is no straight cast. You need to pick an element of the list to use. If you want to return a single value, change the return type from IEnumerable<type> to just type.

Comment: Thanks @akton. actually I couldn't get you earlier. But it worked. Can you pelase guide how I can modify my query to return just requried proerty and not full object using var ? I want to write a query soemthing liek: 
context.Signatories1Repository.Query((a => a.Id == obj.Id).First().Select(x=>x.Name));   

and code of my Query mehtod is mentioned in question.